# Bounded optimization using the Hessian matrix (scipy)

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am trying to optimize a function of a small number of variables (somewhere from 2 to 10). What I am trying to do is calculate the minimum of the function on a bounded hypercube

`[0,1] x [0,1] x ... x [0,1]`

The calculation of the function, its gradient and its hessian is al relatively simple, quick and accurate.

Now, my problem is this:

Using `scipy`, I can use either `scipy.optimize.minimize(..., method='Newton-CG')` or `scipy.optimize.minimize(..., method='TNC')` to calculate the minimum of the function, however:

- The first method uses the Hessian matrix, but I cannot set the bounds for the variables I am optimizing
- The second method allows me to set bounds on the variables, but the method does not use the Hessian.

Is there any method that will use both?

Comment: why is a jacobian not enough in your case ?

Comment: You could try cyipopt

Comment: @Moritz well, generally, using the hessian will speed up performance and demant fewer evaluations of the funcion.

Comment: I know, but if these algorithms do not use it, it doesnt mean they are not equally good or better. You ask for Newton methods with constraints

Comment: @Moritz Yes, I am looking for Newton's methods with constraints. Is there a reason it is not implemented in `scipy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternatives:

[Mystic](http://trac.mystic.cacr.caltech.edu/project/mystic/wiki), a framework which enables constraint optimization by using external constraints (I think, Lagrange multipliers). The package uses scipy.optimize, so it should be possible to use Scipy`s methods with additional constraints.

Ipopt, and its python bindings [PyIpopt](https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt) and [CyIpopt](http://pythonhosted.org/ipopt/index.html). You could look into [openopt](http://openopt.org/Welcome).

Usually developed for curve fitting, [lmfit](http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/) provides the possibility to add external constraints. It has most solvers from scipy included.

Comment: lmfit is probably the easiest to start with.

Comment: @5xum, you accepted this answer so did you find an implementation of a bounded newton algorithm. Note that general constraint optimization algorithms are probably not what you are looking for if your constraints are simply bounds on the input parameters. You will probably want to use something dedicated to this. (Such as l-bfgs-b which unfortunately does not use second order information.)

Answer (score 1):

l-bfgs-b does a bounded optimisation. Like any quasi-Newton method it approximates the Hessian. But this is often better than using the real Hessian.

Comment: Not what the OP requested but sometimes 'the next best thing' is the best that can be done. Note however that your statement that quasi-Newton is often better is vague and misleading. Newton's method is almost always better than a quasi-Newton methods in terms of the number of steps. If a cheap analytic Hessian is available it will greatly outperform the quasi-Newton method. If however the Hessian is not cheaply available and has to be computed from finite differences it will often be cheaper to use a quasi-Newton method in order to avoid the N^2 function evaluates required per step.